# Selecting a submit button with Python (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to automate a Github repository with Python (Selenium)while I use cmd.
I got to the last step: 'Create a new repository' on Github, but can't let python click on "Create repository".

Thanks for every help.

I have tried:
`searchBar = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.first-in-line').click()`
and 
`searchBar = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.first-in-line').submit()`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary first-in-line" data-disable-with="Creating repository…">
        Create repository
</button>
```

I expect that python automatically clicks on the "Create repository" submit button, to finish the new git repository.

Comment: What error or result do you get when you try these things?

Comment: use the GitHub API

Answer (score 1):

When you use `find_elements_by_css_selector` it will return a list.Instead of `find_elements_by_css_selector` you must use `find_element_by_css_selector`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.first-in-line').click()
```

However if you want to use `find_elements_by_css_selector` then you should use index to get the first match and then click like below code.

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.first-in-line')[0].click()
```

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Create repository** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary.first-in-line"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary first-in-line']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: From what I saw, GitHub website is mostly synchronous, and I don't find any clue in the question that implies that the problem is related to timings (though I admit that I haven't tried it myself). How did you get to that conclusion? I know that timing is a pretty common problem but often people assume that a problem is related to timing when it's not, and just introduce unnecessary complexity into the test code which also often hides the real problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
searchBar = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.button.first-in-line').click()
```

One thing, always try to use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` which help you to minimize lot of errors.

Comment: 1. A dot in a css selector signifies a class name. As the element mentioned in the question doesn't have a "button" class, your suggestion isn't going to work.

Comment: 2. The advise to always use xpath is at least debatable if not a bad advise, especially when class names are concerned. See https://www.apress.com/in/blog/all-blog-posts/best-practices-for-choosing-locators-for-selenium/16169400 for more details